# Very simple attempt to deserialize JSON with JSON.NET does not work

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization

I get the error below... Something is very wrong :( any ideas?   (This is in a Windows Phone 8 app)

An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code

And the code is

```
  string responseBody = @" {""HighScoreId"":1,""Name"":""Debra Garcia"",""Score"":2.23},{""HighScoreId"":2,""Name"":""Thorsten Weinrich"",""Score"":2.65}";

            GlobalHighScore s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlobalHighScore>(responseBody);
```

and the class is

```
  public class GlobalHighScore
{
    public int HighScoreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has more than one object, and neither are in an array. You either need to remove one of the objects from the JSON or add them to an array and deserialize them properly:

```
string responseBody = 
    @"[
        {""HighScoreId"":1,""Name"":""Debra Garcia"",""Score"":2.23},
        {""HighScoreId"":2,""Name"":""Thorsten Weinrich"",""Score"":2.65}
    ]";

var highScores = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GlobalHighScore>>(responseBody);
```

Comment: I change the string to this.. same exact error string responseBody = @"[ {""HighScoreId"":1,""Name"":""Debra Garcia"",""Score"":2.23},{""HighScoreId"":2,""Name"":""Thorsten Weinrich"",""Score"":2.65} ]";

Comment: Though when I changed it to ONE object in the list it worked..... oh..wait LIST!! doh!